# Why can we not use the Where Clause on a Grouped statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

For a simplified example of my issue, why could I not do this?

```
select id_number, sum(revenue)
from table A
where sum(revenue)>1000
group by id_number
```

(In case this causes any confusion, why can I not only return the results that have over 1000 in revenue?)

Disclaimer, I'm somewhat new to SQL but couldn't find any documentation regarding this.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to use `having` instead of `where` (after the `group by`), when your condition is on aggregated data.

Comment: You could use `where revenue > 1000` to filter the individual rows prior to aggregation.

Comment: That is not going to work because he wants the sum of all of his products. Therefore, if he has five products that are $999 each, his total would turn up as $0 because none of them started off greater than $1000.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design of SQL. By using WHERE You filter the source table. And the sequence of statement fragments is as written. That means You would like to filter the SUM which is applied on filtered table. That means You must use filter on already grouped result using HAVING clause. Use

```
 select id_number, sum(revenue)
 from table A     
 group by id_number
 having sum(revenue) > 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is because the WHERE clause is evaluated before the aggregation clause. Therefore, you are trying to filter based on something that doesn't exist yet. However, you can solve that problem by making it exist first. Write a subquery, then select from that:

```
WITH RevenueTotals AS (SELECT id_number, sum(revenue) AS Rev_Total 
                       FROM table A 
                       GROUP BY id_number)
SELECT id_number, Rev_Total
FROM RevenueTotals
WHERE Rev_Total > 1000
```